# how can I print out an object nested inside a mongoose schema?

Tags: mongoose

I want to print out each post a user has. However, the post objects nested inside the user are not outputed as I want. This is the user schema:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    profile_picture: String,
    about: String,
    posts: [
      {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: "post"
      }
    ],
    /*
    friends: [
      {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: "friend"
      }
   ],
   relationship_status: { type: String, enum: ['Open', 'Closed', 'Pending'] }*/
});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

and this is the post schema:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    image: String,
    description: String,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("post", PostSchema);
```

This is what I used to print it out:

```
<% user.posts.forEach(function(post){ %>
    <h1><%= post.title %></h1>
    <p><%= post.description %></p>
    <h2><%= post.image %></h2>
<% }) %>
```

This doesn't seem to work, but when I try to print out the id(post._id) it prints out the ids of each post. what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For load nested objects inside the mongoose, you need to use the populate function:

- Mongoose documentation is: [Moongose Documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

In your case, when you seach the user you need to populate the posts.

```
 User.
  findOne({ _id: '507f167e810c14739de860ef' }).
  populate('posts').
  exec(function (err, user) {
    ...
  });
```

- If you want to reproduce this behavior for all calls, you can configure your schema 
  with this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-autopopulate.